# Mysql while variable inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql

after having searched for the last 5 hours I cannot figure out why this code does not work...

It does however work as expected if I remove the INSERT line inside the loop???

I am using Mysql 5.5 on Debian.

Any help please? Thank you in advance.

```
 SET @j = 0;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureYearWeek(INOUT j INT)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Periods WHERE perPeriods NOT IN (0);
        WHILE j < 10 DO
            INSERT INTO Periods (perPeriods) VALUES (YEARWEEK(ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL j DAY)));
            SELECT j + 1 INTO j;
        END WHILE;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL procedureYearWeek(@j);
```

Comment: What is the expected result?  What is it supposed to do?  What is not working?

Comment: I need the while loop to insert the YEARWEEK() values into the Periods tables 10 time ie 201704, 201705, 201706 etc. It looks like the j following the INTERVAL does not get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, turned out to be my inexperience with Mysql together with a silly mistake.
This is the answer:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureYearWeek()
BEGIN
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newDAta INT DEFAULT 0;
    DELETE FROM Periods WHERE perPeriods NOT IN (0);
        WHILE j < 10 DO
            INSERT INTO Periods (perPeriods) VALUES (YEARWEEK(ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL newDAta DAY)));
            SET j = j + 1;
            SET newDAta = newDAta + 14;
        END WHILE;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```